# How do I turn a symbol , that has underscores (e.g. The_Dark_Knight), when the symbol is a key in a hash into a string with spaces in between words?

Tags: ruby, string, hash, symbols

I'm new to coding and have only been doing this for about 12 days so forgive my n00biness. I decided to learn Ruby first as it's not particularly hard to get the hang of. I'm making a small program that tracks and stores information from users. In this particular section of the code I want to track and store how the user rated a particular movie. I've been playing around with a few features such as adding, displaying, deleting and updating the movies (these four elements are the "whens" as part of a case statement). I have hit a roadblock on the displaying part.

The hash, in question, I've been using to test the program is (Disclaimer: movie ratings were not intended to offend):

```
movies = {
  The_Dark_Knight: 10,
  Justice_League: 1,
  Wolverine_Origins: 7,
  Wonder_Woman: 6,
  Man_of_Steel: 8 
}
```

and I want Ruby to display the title of the movies in the hash (after iterating through them) alongside the ratings as such:

```
=begin 
The Dark Knight: 10
Justice League: 1
Wolverine Origins: 7 
Wonder Woman: 6
Man of Steel: 8 
=end
```

This is the display part of the case statement. 'When' the user selects display it should show them the titles of the movie alongside the rating as shown above.

```
when "display"

movies.each {|title, rating|

title_as_string = title.to_s.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')

puts "#{title_as_string}: #{rating}"
}
```

This is the way I went about it and believe me when I tell you it took me very long to figure that out. It got me the result I wanted but...

...The question is: Is there a more concise or better way to do this? If so, how?

Answers will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would use a white space inside the symbol from the beginning already. What's the point in having an underscore in one case and a space in the other case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do the same thing.

1. You can use [`String#gsub`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) - this stands for "global substitution" which is exactly what you want to do - substitute `_` for a space:

   ```
     title_as_string = title.to_s.gsub("_", " ")
   ```

   You could also use [`String#tr`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr) - the method doesn't do the exact same thing but in this case you could replace `gsub` with `tr` and it would have the same result
2. Use strings as keys. It's not as easy to write it out because you need to use hashrocket (`=>`) syntax but removes the whole need for the substitution:

   ```
     movies = {
       "The Dark Knight" => 10,
       "Justice League" => 1,
       # etc
     }
   ```
3. Put spaces in your symbols - this approach isn't as commonly used but it is totally valid syntax:

   ```
     movies = {
       "The Dark Knight": 10,
       "Justice League": 1,
       # etc
     }
   ```

   <strike>The only</strike> One difference between this and string keys is I have replaced the hashrocket `=>` with colon `:`. You still need to call `.to_s` in this case but don't need to do the substitution. **As engineersmnky pointed out in a comment there are other differences ... probably I wouldn't advise this approach because it's not very common**
4. Use a "data object" pattern. This is a little more verbose but more explicit as well:

   ```
     movies = {
       The_Dark_Knight: {
         name: "The Dark Knight",
         rating: 10
       },
       Justice_League: {
         name: "Justice League",
         rating: 1
       }
     }

     movies.each {|key, data|
       title_as_string = data[:name]
       rating = data[:rating]
       # etc
     }
   ```

   This might seem redundant, but it is actually more flexible - what if you stored these movies in the database and wanted to use the ID as the key for the hash instead? That way you could quickly look up records given their ID.

One other thing, you should be using `do ... end` for your multiline blocks. Only use braces for oneliner blocks.

Comment: #3 `:"The Dark Knight"` and `"The Dark Knight"` are not the same thing for example `h = {"The Dark Knight": 12,"The Dark Knight" => 10}` is a valid 2 key 2 value `Hash` accessible as `h[:"The Dark Knight"] #=> 12` and `h["The Dark Knight"] #=> 10`

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah, maybe it wasn't accurate of me to say "the only difference", but I was speaking about OP's example code and not _how the hash is interacted with in general_.

Comment: The reason I was not using the hash rocket syntax is because I was taught they updated the hash syntax in Ruby 1.9 similar to that of Javascript objects and Python dictionaries (colon after the key followed by a space then, the value).  So is hash rocket syntax still valid and used? It kinda makes life easier.

Comment: Also: Is it just personal preference? Though hash rocket style is not as easy to type out it kind of makes storing and recalling information from/in indexes more manageable.

Comment: @4LB5_ The "new" syntax (with colon) makes the keys _symbols_. If you want your keys to have spaces in them, it's better to make them _strings_ (for which you use hashrocket syntax)